# Income tax loss credit after depreciation on negatively geared property

Tags: income-tax, investing, australia

In Australia, my personal taxable income for a particular financial year before calculating depreciation on an investment property is very low (close to but above $0). This is after adding all rental income and deducting interest expenses, etc.

If my investment property depreciation for the FY brings my taxable income below $0 (say, for example, -$10,000), can that loss be carried forward as a credit for next FY?

Comment: Do you do your taxes by hand or with software? Typically, the software will show you a 'carryover' form if you are able to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you have little income in  one year and your expenses are more than your total income in that year, then any losses can be carried forward to a future income year in which you actually do have a taxable income.

One thing to consider though, your first $18,200 in income is Tax free, so in a future Income Year, after deductions, if your Taxable Income is $18,200 or less you will still have to utilise the tax loss from previous years in that Income Year, even though you wouldn't pay any tax anyway. This is because you must utilise a tax loss at the first opportunity, and you cannot defer the loss to a year where your income is more than $18,200.

The deductions you cannot use to create or increase a tax loss, including donations, gifts and personal super contributions. So you can deduct your depreciation on your investment property to derive a tax loss.

Comment: Thanks Victor. Specifically what I am hoping to confirm is whether depreciation on an investment property is counted towards a loss that can be carried forward. My understanding is that some "expenses" can be deducted from your taxable income but cannot be included in the calculation of a loss to be carried forward. I don't know if this is accurate or which expenses this rule applies to.

Comment: From the ATO website: "Certain deductions cannot be used to contribute to a loss." https://www.ato.gov.au/General/Losses/

Comment: @JoGoFo - I have updated my answer regarding not being able to defer a tax loss and about deductions not allowed to create or increase a tax loss.